# Trouble with array manipulation php

Tags: php, arrays

I've been trying for some hours now, and I can't manage to get done what I want, i'm sure you guys will do better than me :

I've got two arrays like this ($aOldSales) :

```
array (size=24)
  0 => 
    array (size=5)
      'cslId' => string '1844' (length=4)
      etc..
  1 => 
    array (size=5)
      'cslId' => string '1725' (length=4)
      etc..
  2 => etc...
```

and like this ($aOldSalesInfos(big one)) :

```
array (size=390)
  0 => 
    array (size=8)
      'careId' => string '15804' (length=5)
       more infos here...
      'cslId' => string '1844' (length=4)
  1 => 
    array (size=8)
      'careId' => string '12031' (length=5)
       more infos here...
      'cslId' => string '1844' (length=4)
  2 => etc...
```

What I actually want is that ($aOldSales):

```
array (size=24)
  0 => 
    array (size=6)
      'cslId' => string '1844' (length=4)
      'caresinfos' => 
        array (size=8)
          'careId' => string '15804' (length=5)
           more infos...
           more infos...
          'cslId' => string '1844' (length=4)
        array (size=8)
          'careId' => string '15805' (length=5)
           more infos...
           more infos...
          'cslId' => string '1844' (length=4)
```

what I tried so far (I tried different little thing, but thats the idea) :

```
for($i=0;$i<count($aOldSales);$i++)
{
    for($cpt=0;$cpt<count($aOldSalesInfos);$cpt++)
    {
        if($aOldSales[$i]['cslId'] == $aOldSalesInfos[$cpt]['cslId'])
        {
            $aOldSales[$i]['caresinfos'] = $aOldSalesInfos[$cpt];
        }
    }
}
```

I get kind of an encouraging result, as 'careinfos' is filled with **1** array with a correct "care(consider it as a produt)" but not all of them...

I hope it was clear enough and I didn't get too confusing, if you have any questions, or if I forgot sth, don't hesitate to leave a comment!

Big thanks to you guys :)

Comment: You should join stuff at query time.

Comment: I know, I already tried when that was query time, but failed and still went on, now it would question all my current code to go back on the query stuff... :/ but I do agree

Comment: `$aOldSales[$i]['caresinfos'][] = $aOldSalesInfos[$cpt];`

Comment: Oh @Jack, frow what i'm seeing so far its working! So logical, yet it didn't come up in my tiny brain...

Comment: if @Jack comment solves your problem, urge him to posted it as answer and accept it.

Comment: Well it's up to him, it did solve my problem there's no doubt about that ! :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your inner loop code:

```
if ($aOldSales[$i]['cslId'] == $aOldSalesInfos[$cpt]['cslId']) {
    $aOldSales[$i]['caresinfos'] = $aOldSalesInfos[$cpt];
}
```

Is overwriting the same array element each time; to create a growing array of elements you need to use the `[]` operator:

```
if ($aOldSales[$i]['cslId'] == $aOldSalesInfos[$cpt]['cslId']) {
    $aOldSales[$i]['caresinfos'][] = $aOldSalesInfos[$cpt];
}
```

See also: [Creating/modifying with square bracket syntax](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax.modifying)